# Change the "length" of a tab delimited file in C#?

Tags: c#

I've got a tab delimited  file like so that I am reading into an array:

```
string[] yourChoicesItems = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt"); 
aaaaaaaaa(tab)0.09
aaa(tab)1.25
```

The problem is, when I display the array in a text box, it ends up looking something like this:

```
aaaaaaaaa    0.09
aaa    0.09
```

I want the 2nd column to line up. In Word, I'd just change the tab stops, but when I Googled "Tab stops" + C# I got something completely different.

Comment: How are you reading it?

Comment: can you show the code that you are using also you can do a .Trim() on the data once you have done the splitting into the array

Comment: You're probably facing a two fold problem, first the font is probably not something like Consolas (I am struggling to grab the term for that type of font) and the next problem (though it may be moot if you change the font) is that you may have to replace the tabs with spaces when viewing the text.

Comment: Clarify what this is as well `aaaaaaaaa(tab)0.09
aaa(tab)1.25` if that's a tab char leave it out and show it as a space so it make sense can't tell what you're trying to truly represent..`CANT TELL NOT RECOMMEND ANYTHING WITHOUT CODE SAMPLE`

Comment: @AshReva string[] yourChoicesItems = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");

Comment: @DJ KRAZE I could write it as spaces, but the point is, it's a single tab character. The equivalent of  "\t" in C#.

Comment: I am quite aware I am just trying to make sure that I was understanding what I was seeing / looking at..

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, text boxes aren't really designed to handle formatted text as far as I'm aware. There's `RichTextBox` of course - but I'm not sure even that would handle tabs the way that you want it to just by default.

With a plain text box you *could* set the font to something fixed-width, and then replace each tab with a different number of spaces depending on how far through the line it was... but that's a lot of faff to display fundamentally-tabular data in a control which really wasn't designed for that purpose.

You should consider something along the lines of a grid view instead - split the lines by tabs, and each line becomes a row of data. It's a much more appropriate control for the task at hand, I suspect.

Comment: @StenPetrov: That's pretty much what I said, isn't it? "I'm not sure even that would handle tabs the way that you want it to just by default." (It's possible there's something cunning you can do within rich text, but it's likely to be a pain in the neck, and it's still not really the right solution IMO.)

Comment: @Jon: people just live to try and find a hole in one of your answers. LOL. People hate it when people are right, well pretty much all the time! Fantastic answer, and I would +1 if I had any more votes left for today.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] records = inputString.Split('\n');
foreach(var record in records)
{
   string[] fields = record.Split('\t');
   // do stuff with the fields, here, (independently of tabs) 
}
```

**edit** @JonSkeet beat me to it by 30 seconds, but I'm leaving this code sample b/c his answer lacks one

Answer (score 1):

To line them up in your textboxes split your input then join it back with String.Format:

```
string[] parts= record.Split('\t');
string yourOutput = string.Format("{0,-15}{1}", parts[0], parts[1]);
```

Of course some input checking would be good... and what you're asking for still probably needs  to be revised and have separate controls for each part you're showing

Comment: So now, I end up back where I started except instead of a tab between them, there's a constant 15 spaces.

Comment: @user2146821 didn't you want to line them up? this format will fill the first value to be a total of 15 characters at least. Using fixed width font will line up multiple of them

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/0d267009-5480-4314-8929-d4f8d8687cfd) answer. You haven't specified whether you are using wpf or wf but it should be something similar.